# Kernel and Image for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given A linear transformation $T:M_{3\times3}^{R}\rightarrow M_{3\times3}^{R}\qquad T(X)=AX$
  for all $X\in M_{3\times3}^{R}$
 .
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & -2\\
2 & -1 & 5\\
-2 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
 $.

I need to find a basis for $kerT$
  and $ImT$
 .

I did it but it's really long and not elegant.

does someone has any idea how to solve it shortly?

Comment: what exactly did you do?

Comment: @abel I did a long way finiding a matrix which its dimension is $9\times9$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for kernel**

Note that $A$ can be reduced to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & -2\\
0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus $\begin{bmatrix}-4\\-3\\1 \end{bmatrix} \in \text{ker }A$.

So for $X \in \text{ker }T$. You can have 
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 0 & 0\\
-3 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now think what other forms of $X$ are possible which are linearly independent from this one. This will help you get a basis for the kernel of $T$.